# How to expect possible undefined value with double object bracket notation?

Tags: javascript

For example, given:

```
const foo = {name: 'john', age: 12}

console.log(foo?.age);
```

Given the previous, we are safeguarding by using `?` in case `foo` doesn't have the property `age` but how can it be done in the next situation (if possible):

```
const foo = {name: 'john', house: {color: 'white', garage: true }}
console.log(foo['house']?['yard']
```

How to access a property, inside the property `house` that might be undefined by using brackets?

Comment: Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Comment: It's still `?.`. Looks weird: `?.["yard"]`.

Comment: should be foo['house']?.['yard']

Answer (score 2):

First you have a big understanding of the null safe operator, when you say `foo?.age` you're not safeguarding `age` field but the foo object itself, examples:

1. `{a: 2}?.age` and `{a: 2}.age` return the same thing, no error will be thrown in both cases, just the value `undefined` is returned.
2. `undefined?.age` and `undefined.age` are different, the first will return `undefined` while the second will throw an error.

Now after you understand what is the null safe operator about, to prevent `foo["house"]` from throwing because `foo` might be undefined (not because house property doesn't exist) just use `foo?.["house"]`.

If you want to check for the existence of house property, you can do something like this:

```
if(foo?.["house"]){
    // here house exists so it's safe to read its value using foo.house
}
```

Or:

```
if(foo?.hasOwnProperty("house")){
    // the same thing, safe to access foo.house
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I would encourage using Lodash _.get function when need to read a property, (embedded properties) and when you afraid of having undefined for one of them

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look great, but it's all we've got

```js
const foo = {name: 'john', house: {color: 'white', garage: true }}
console.log(foo['house']?.['yard'])
```